# Center align plain text (php)

Tags: php, javascript, dialog

I have been asked to come up with a solution which would allow our users to create their own custom javascript dialog text. However we need it to be centered.

At the moment, we have a textarea, which the user pads using spaces and tests with a preview button. I would like to change this to allow for the text to be center aligned automatically. I think this would mean just adding the spaces myself line by line in the backend, and also adding in the correct line breaks.

The only way I can think of doing it, is getting the longest line as `int`, and then subtracting subsequent lines from it, and diving the result by two, and tacking that many spaces on front and back.

Is there a cleaner more elegant way to approach this problem? Are there ways of aligning text actually inside the dialog?

I had considered something like TinyMCE, but I think it's a little overkill, for what is essentially a 150 character, 4-5 line string.

Comment: Is this plaintext displayed in a `<pre>` tag?

Comment: Nope, in a javascript confirmation dialog.

Comment: Its never going to work very well - you don't know/can't control the font used in a dialog - so you can't determine what size the characters are. Its always going to look messy.

Comment: (unless you skip the whole javascript dialog thing and go with a modal DIV - where you can use CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the PHP side, you can do this.

```
$lines=array();
foreach (explode("\n",wordwrap($str,$len=80)) as $line)
  $lines[]=str_pad($line,$len,' ',STR_PAD_BOTH);
echo implode("\n",$lines);
```

The Javascript version should be easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-format.php) has a useful javascript function for center-aligning a string using padding. Assuming you're displaying plain fixed-width text (using a `<pre>` tag or similar) then you'll need to get the length of the longest line and pad accordingly. If not, it's just a matter of setting the css: `#myDiv { text-align:center; }` on the div containing the text.